# Google Fonts are not rendering on Windows

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am developing a Wordpress Theme; I've imported many stylesheets and some Google Fonts, everything works perfectly well on a MAC but when I test my site on Windows, it is not detecting my Google Fonts, I've tried a couple of ways to import it on my `functions.php` file but same results. I've tested on Edge, Chrome and Firefox and it has the same issue.

I've tried:

1. Importing on `style.css` file using `@import`  - No results.
2. Registering the style using `wp_register_style` and `wp_enqueue_style` - No results.

I'll leave my `functions.php` file below.

```
function wp_bulldoezer_styles() {
        wp_register_style('raleway', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,500,600,700,800');
        wp_register_style('hind', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:400,300,500,600,700');

        $query_args = array(
                'family' => 'Raleway:400,300,500,600,700,800|Hind:400,300,500,600,700',
            );    

        wp_register_style( 'google-fonts', add_query_arg( $query_args, "//fonts.googleapis.com/css" ), array(), null );

        wp_enqueue_style('google-fonts');
        wp_enqueue_style('raleway');
        wp_enqueue_style('hind');

    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_bulldoezer_styles');
```

And in my CSS File:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,500,600,700,800);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:400,300,500,600,700);
```

You can test the site on this [URL](http://copsesanluis.com/b), the fonts I want to import are Raleway and Hind both are available on Google Fonts.

Hove you guys can help me solve this problem it's been kinda messy.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

The content is rendered in an `iframe`. None of the resources included in the `<head>` will be available inside an `iframe`. This, of course, includes all CSS, and thus, also the fonts.